# Formatting results of a polynomial long division (Extension for finite fields)

Tags: formatting, polynomials, finite-fields

I've just read [Formatting results of a polynomial long division](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/35476/formatting-results-of-a-polynomial-long-division/35496#35496?newreg=30648c34699f4e389ebd2aa0de08fd91) with great interest. For my teaching purposes it would be great to enable the code given in that post to treat polynomial division with coefficients from a finite field. Is there a simple way to do that?

Code:

```
Column@{WolframAlpha["polynomial long division (y^3-6y+20)/(y-3)",{{"QuotientAndRemainder", 1}, "Content"}, PodStates -> {"QuotientAndRemainder__Step-by-step solution"}], WolframAlpha["polynomial long division (y^3-6y+20)/(y-3)", {{"QuotientAndRemainder", 2}, "Content"}, PodStates -> {"QuotientAndRemainder__Step-by-step solution"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is no easy solution. I wrote a ruby script that fulfills the task. It produces command line and latex output. It can be downloaded from https://github.com/demogorgi/polynomialLongDivision

Example:

Arguments are dividend, divisor, charakteristic of the finite field, variable symbol

```
>ruby pd.rb "3,0,0,1,1" "4,0,3" 5 x
```

yields (among other things):

```
  (   1x⁴ + 1x³             + 3  ) : (   3x²       + 4  ) =    2x² + 2x  + 4
- (   1x⁴       + 3x² )
-------------------------------------------------------------
            1x³ + 2x²
      - (   1x³       + 3x )
-------------------------------------------------------------
                  2x² + 2x  + 3
            - (   2x²       + 1 )
-------------------------------------------------------------
                        2x  + 2
```

Comment: Can you please show how to call this from within the Wolfram Language & Mathematica? Thanks!

Comment: You can use `RunProcess[$SystemShell, "StandardOutput", "ruby pd.rb '3,0,0,1,1' '4,0,3' 5 x"]`
But you have to comment line 260 and other code lines that produce undesired output. If it doesn't work use StandardError instead of StandardOutput. [`ExternalEvaluate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExternalEvaluate.html) might also be an option if you really want to run the code from within Mathematica.